# FlatList is not Re-Rendering on Props Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

My flatlist will not re-render when the props change. In this case I go to another page and add a new list item and when I come back to this list it still has the old data. The new item is not there until I refresh. I have the extra data set to the correct props but it won't work.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container, Text, Icon, Left, Right, ListItem, Thumbnail, Body, Content } from 'native-base';
import { removeDog, addDog } from '../actions';

class MyDogs extends Component {

    renderList() {
        if (this.props.myDogs.lendth === 0) {
            return (
                <Text>You have no saved dogs</Text>
            );
        }
        return (
            <FlatList 
            extraData={this.props.myDogs}
            data={this.props.myDogs}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem avatar>
                        <Left>
                            <Thumbnail 
                            source={{ uri: item.photo }} 
                            square
                            />
                        </Left>
                        <Body>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text note>{item.breed}</Text>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                            <Icon name='arrow-forward' />
                        </Right>
                    </ListItem>
                );
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.myDogs);
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    {this.renderList()}      
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        myDogs: state.dogs.myDogs 
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { removeDog, addDog })(MyDogs);
```

Here is my reducer

```js
import {
    ADD_DOG,
    REMOVE_DOG
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    myDogs: [],
    rejectedDogs: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    let breedString = '';
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_DOG:
           // ... making breed string removed
                breedString = action.payload.breeds.breed.$t;
            
            state.myDogs.push({
                name: action.payload.name.$t,
                photo: action.payload.media.photos.photo[1].$t,
                id: action.payload.id.$t,
                breed: breedString.slice(0, -2)
            });
            return { ...state,
                myDogs: state.myDogs
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is where I combine the reducers

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import FindDogsReducer from './FindDogsReducer';
import BreedReduce from './BreedReducer';
import SettingsReducer from './SettingsReducer';
import DogsReducer from './DogsReducer';


export default combineReducers({
    findDogsReducer: FindDogsReducer,
    dogs: DogsReducer,
    breeds: BreedReduce,
    settings: SettingsReducer
});
```

Comment: `FlatList` is a `PureComponent` so it will not re-render unless the references given to it change. Are you sure your Redux updates are immutable?

Comment: I am not sure my redux updates are immutable. I am learning redux and react-native.

Comment: That's alright. Could you perhaps include your Redux code that updates `dogs` and `myDogs`?

Comment: Sure. I added them above.

Comment: Is it because I am pushing to state.myDogs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlatList` is a `PureComponent` so it will not re-render unless the references given to it change. You are currently using `push` to add a new object to your `myDogs` array, which will mutate the current state.

You instead want to create an entirely new array which contains all the dogs currently in state and your new one, and it will work:

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  let breedString = "";

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DOG:
      breedString = action.payload.breeds.breed.$t;

      return {
        ...state,
        myDogs: [
          ...state.myDogs,
          {
            name: action.payload.name.$t,
            photo: action.payload.media.photos.photo[1].$t,
            id: action.payload.id.$t,
            breed: breedString.slice(0, -2)
          }
        ]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: You sir are a hero. Thank you for the help!

Comment: how would I do this when I'm updating an element of the array, not adding or removing? I tried using `extraData` with that, but it does not work

Comment: the new array (appended items to original array) is causing the flatlist parent component to re render due to connect(). So flatlist is also re rendering the entire array (even the ones that has already been re rendered)